# How to assist your home university in evaluating whether classes taken when studying abroad should allow transfer of credit?

Tags: transfer-student, abroad

I am going to be studying for 1 semester in Japan for my computer science degree. This 1 semester will earn me my degree as well as my required internship. 
I was already accepted into TU and am in the process of my transfer credits but my advisor at TU is concerned that some of the classes I took here, in the US, don't touch on everything they do over in TU.

How should you compare two courses to help an advisor determine if the courses are similar enough to transfer credits?

Comment: The comparison is the job of whoever confirms the credit transfer. Ask them what documents they need from you.

Comment: Dig up the syllabi (syllabuses!) or ask the professors if they still have copies.

Comment: which is more important? the learning or the certification of the learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit the course (or module-) descriptions for the examination department/office.
The target university needs a basis for their decisions to make.

A description of the course containing information about the topic (a syllabus), learning goals and skills taught, the workload and the examination conditions, will help to decide whether a course fits into your major or not and if it can be granted with transfer credits and so on.